# asp.net dropdownlist first selection does not fire SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've created a dropdownlist, and tried clicking on the first selection but there was no firing of the SelectedIndexChanged event. However, it worked perfectly fine for the rest of the options in the dropdownlist.

Here are my codes:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string member = (String)Session["ssmem"];
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["ssmem"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("LoginforAccess.aspx");

        else
        {
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

           //if go back then must log in --2
        }

        //Dropdownlist
        string strConnectionString =
                  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        //STEP1 : Define a connection to Database 
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strcommand = "Select Username from [User] WHERE (UsergroupID = (SELECT UsergroupID FROM [User] AS User_1 WHERE (Username = @user)))";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcommand, myConnect);
        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usergrp", groupid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", member);

        myConnect.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        DropDownList1.DataSource = reader;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Username";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Username";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        reader.Close();
        myConnect.Close();
    }



}

  protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    if (Session["ssmem"] != null)
        MasterPageFile = "User.master";
    //change the master page --1
}
   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //chosen name to display stats
    string choseuser = "";
    choseuser = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Substats.aspx?choseuser=" + choseuser);
}
 }
```

Source view for dropdownlist:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="35px" 
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    ViewStateMode="Enabled">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Isn't it because your first item is already selected when you load the page?

Comment: You do not seem to have a default option in your dropdown, something like "-- select something --", thus your first option from DB is already selected. So when you select it again, you basically selected nothing new, selection index does not change, and event does not get triggered

Answer (score 0):

```html
We have to add first item as title to the dropdownlist,
and instead of using datasource used dr.Read() in while loop for adding the items on dropdownlist.

This problem occurs because in dropdownlist first item is selected bydefault and it is not reflected on selection  


<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            <asp:ListItem>Select College</asp:ListItem> 
<!--Add one item as title into dropdownlist in edit item of dropdownlist-->
        </asp:DropDownList>

 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write("hello");
            try
            {
                string sel = "select name from websites";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sel,con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               /* DropDownList1.DataSource = dr;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();*/
                while (dr.Read())//used dr.read() instead of datasource
                {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select url from websites where name = @itm", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itm", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                Response.Redirect(dr["url"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would un-indent your first explanatory sentences.  Then it's clearer to differentiate them from the code itself.